# Playstation Eye with Labiew

Tags: labview, playstation

Does anyone know how to integrate the Playstation Eye with Labview? Can a driver somehow be used to allow Labview to recognize it as a webcam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with vision (install IMAQdx and Vision Dev Module)- it seems to be DirectShow, which IMAQ can do- or try out the code found on this page: http://www.labviewforum.de/thread-21279.html - it uses the original dlls.

Comment: Sadly, IMAQ doesnt seem to recognize it, I will look into the dll option, but it would be nice if there was a Labview option I could use.

Comment: Do you have IMAQdx ? You could also try the camera configurator.. or try if ADVision http://vi-lib.com/ can do it.

Comment: It seems that it appears in the Measurement & Automation Explorer, but not with the IMAQdx example! Not sure what to do there. I thought it was a driver issue, turns out it's something else.

Comment: Can you do grab/snap in MAX? If so, try the vision express acquisation vi.. - and then turn it into regular labview code. 
If not, it can still be a driver issue. You have downloaded the PC drivers, yes?

Comment: What do you mean by PC drivers? I downloaded the drivers for the camera (it shows up in Measurement & Automation as cam3)

Answer (score 0):

as there are NO official dll´s for the PS3 Eye on Windows, the ONLY Option is to use the 3rd Party drivers from Code Laboratries or directly interface the Hardware via USB-RAW commands. Code Laboratries PS3 Implementation however does not seem to be 100% conform with the Direct Show standard. You can get a PS3 Eye to work with Labview (via Direct Show and IMAQ), but you will be limited by the usable framerates.

I tried to interface the dll from code laboratries directly, but got stuck on a stange error with the second function i tried (see the already referenced Thread http://www.labviewforum.de/thread-21279.html). However it seems as for now there is a Vi Package available for the PS3 Eye to support  LabView under OSX with the full available framerate. More Information can be found here:
http://labview.epfl.ch/

Hope this helps.
Best Regards,
Jan